# How rename specific columns in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, multiple-columns, rename

I have a dataframe in PySpark, result of a `groupBy` with `agg`. Like this:

```py
df1 = df.groupBy(['data', 'id']).pivot('type').agg(F.sum('value').alias("Values"), F.count('value').alias("Quantity"))
```

But I need to put the alias ("Values" and "Quantity) as the prefix of these columns, not as the suffix.

This is the example of dataframe.

Result of my script:

| data | id | some_type_Values | some_type_Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1234 | 12.50 | 2 |

Desire output:

| data | id | Values some_type | Quantity some_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1234 | 12.50 | 2 |

What I've tried so far:

```py
selected = df1.select([s for s in df1.columns if 'Values' in s])
select_volume = [col(col_name).alias("Values " + col_name)  for col_name in selected.columns]
df2 = df1.select(*select_volume)
```

This works, but splits my dataframe. And I will also need to cut the `_Values` and `_Quantity` at the end of the column.

How can I rename selected columns for each operation and also remove this alias from the end of each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `rfind` may be useful.

Example dataframes:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2022-01-01', 1234, 'some_type_1', 2),
     ('2022-01-01', 1234, 'some_type_2', 3)],
    ['data', 'id', 'type', 'value'])
df1 = df.groupBy(['data', 'id']).pivot('type').agg(F.sum('value').alias("Values"), F.count('value').alias("Quantity"))
df1.show()
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
# |      data|  id|some_type_1_Values|some_type_1_Quantity|some_type_2_Values|some_type_2_Quantity|
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
# |2022-01-01|1234|                 2|                   1|                 3|                   1|
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Script for renaming:

```py
df1 = df1.select(
    *['data', 'id'],
    *[F.col(c).alias(f"{c[c.rfind('_')+1:]} {c[:c.rfind('_')]}") for c in df1.columns if c not in ['data', 'id']]
)
df1.show()
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
# |      data|  id|Values some_type_1|Quantity some_type_1|Values some_type_2|Quantity some_type_2|
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
# |2022-01-01|1234|                 2|                   1|                 3|                   1|
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

---

`toDF` is also possible and it's less verbose, but it can be more prone to error in some cases.

```py
df1 = df1.toDF(
    *['data', 'id'],
    *[f"{c[c.rfind('_')+1:]} {c[:c.rfind('_')]}" for c in df1.columns if c not in ['data', 'id']]
)
df1.show()
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
# |      data|  id|Values some_type_1|Quantity some_type_1|Values some_type_2|Quantity some_type_2|
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
# |2022-01-01|1234|                 2|                   1|                 3|                   1|
# +----------+----+------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```